# Chrome issues with display-inline for <select> <option> tags

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I am having an issue where I cannot get the same bit of CSS to render the same across Firefox and Chrome. Instead of a vertical select box of 24 values, they all appear in a line next to each other in Firefox:

[image]

In Chrome, they appear as a vertical multiple select box.

Complete code for an abbreviated 3 hour example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      option { display: inline; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <select id="aryHours[]" class="select_hours" size="1" multiple="multiple" name="aryHours[]">  
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, the options do not display inline.

Any explanations why this code does/does not work and are there any other ways to achieve the same layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you should (can?) make `<option>` elements inline like that. Try using checkboxes instead. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WVNww/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Inline Options</title>
     <style>
         ul {
             list-style:none;overflow:hidden;
         }
         ul li {
             lit-style:none;
             float:left;
             position:relative;
         }
         ul li input[type="checkbox"] {
             position:absolute;
             top:0;
             right:0;
             bottom:0;
             left:0;
             width:100%;
             height:100%;
             opacity:0;
         }
         ul li input:checked + label {
             background:blue;
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form action="#" method="get">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="aryHours[]" id="checkbox1" />
                 <label for="checkbox1" class="">Option 1</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="aryHours[]" id="checkbox2" />
                 <label for="checkbox2" class="">Option 2</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="aryHours[]" id="checkbox3" />
                 <label for="checkbox3" class="">Option 3</label>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I disagree that options cannot be made inline -- try my code in FireFox. That said, this approach is clever and has the correct basic functionality. However, there are several functional differences that I think are important. Since this was a multiple select, the user has the ability to hold down shift and drag over the hours desired. In this example, the user must individually select each hour. In my real application, there are 24 options, not 3. Having to click up to 24 times is not user-friendly.

Comment: @dsh - Very true, but just 'cause one (or even more than one) browser allows you to get away with it doesn't mean you should do it. I'm not sure what the specs would say, but I'd treat the fact that Firefox allows it as suspect - I mean `<select>` is one of the more difficult controls to style and customize. In my experience, anything past font and color and you're probably resorting to a hack.

Comment: I think you are right that the display property was never meant for options. I used your code to simulate what I was trying to do, and added some javaScript to make it behave more like a checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: What would happen if this is viewed on an iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox behaviour may be due to a bug

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271482

As proposed earlier try to avoid using inline on option